# (Ubuntu 14.04) Mouse hang, then the system hangs

Tags: unity, 14.04

ONLY when i use my track pad/mouse on my laptop and cross the center of it a COUPLE times every thing hangs. Then when i use my external BlurTooth mouse it doesn't hang not once. I Need to know.

how do I fix this cause its annoying?

Also HOW DO I DISABLE the ALT+leftmouse click?.

i would like to use blender and other apps that require this alt+leftmouse click.
This would seriously be the only reason for me to go back to windows(which i dont want to do ever again)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the trackpad, it could be driver issue, so please try another kernel.

And to use ALT in Blender/Maya, disable it from compiz > unity plugin, and from unity tweak tool.

Answer (score 0):

Adam!

I experience that problem and sometimes, I have to do the gentle Linux reboot (REISUB).
What I did is I updated the kernel to 3.14.2 and it worked!

Before doing this, please be **confident** that you will **not break** your computer. Here's how it goes:

**1)** Download the .DEB files of the new version.
    `  32-bit (do all the commands!):

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.2-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.2-031402_3.14.2-031402.201404262053_all.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.2-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.2-031402-generic_3.14.2-031402.201404262053_i386.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.2-utopic/linux-image-3.14.2-031402-generic_3.14.2-031402.201404262053_i386.deb
```

64-bit (do all the commands!):

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.2-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.2-031402_3.14.2-031402.201404262053_all.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.2-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.2-031402-generic_3.14.2-031402.201404262053_amd64.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.2-utopic/linux-image-3.14.2-031402-generic_3.14.2-031402.201404262053_amd64.deb
```

**2)** Install them (same for both architectures):

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.14.2-*.deb linux-image-3.14.2-*.deb
```

**3)** Reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

As for the Blender/Maya issue, I cannot fix it because I'm not an expert for those programs. I'm sorry.